# 1 byte unsigned integer c++

Tags: c++

I have programmed a class called HugeInteger which can do arithmetic (add, sub, multiply) with numbers of "infinitely" size. It treats each bit of the digit in the number as a stand-alone digit (e.g. 1234 = 1, 2, 3 and 4). I store these numbers in a vector `(vector<short>)`. Now, because each digit only can take the values from 0 to 9, i don't really need to store them as a 2 byte digit. Is there a way (without using char) to store the digits as a 1 byte unsigned integer? Thanks!

Update:

```
vector<unsigned char> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);

for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    cout << v[i];
```

This produces an unwanted output. Which datatype should I use to iterate through the vector?

Comment: The header <cstdint> provides a type named "uint8_t" - if your environment supports such a type. Please note that "uint8_t" can be a typedef for 'unsigned char'. So overloading might not work as expected in all cases.

Comment: `unsigned char` is C++'s "one byte unsigned integer" by definition. Why don't you want a solution to your problem?

Comment: @jwodder: I don't know the intentions of the OP, but `char` is not necessarily `unsigned`. This may cause portability issues for values outside [0, 127]

Comment: The OP says values from 0 to 9.

Comment: I stand corrected. I didn't know that you could do something like this:
vector<unsigned char> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
int a = a[0] + a[1];

Comment: No, you can't do `a = a[0] + a[1];`, believe me.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: No, it isn't necessarily one byte.  Don't confuse `sizeof (char)` (always 1) with size in bytes.  `sizeof` returns the size in units of `char`, not bytes.

Comment: @BenVoigt units of `char` are bytes by definition (cf. §1.7p1). Don't confuse byte with 8 bits.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: No, the size of a byte is architecture dependent, but it may not be enough for a `char`.  There are systems with 6 or 7 bit bytes.  Such bytes are not large enough to hold the range of values required for `char` -- on such systems a `char` is more than one byte (and `sizeof (T)` does not return the number of bytes).

Comment: @Ben hmm, [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)? (Check §5.3.3p1, btw)

Comment: By the way, the unwanted output is because you need to cast to int when passing to a stream, unless you really want to avoid that, but the unsigned char is precisely what you want

Comment: What if you wanted to output a number, though?

Comment: This is late, but you can use a bit field if you want.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, use `unsigned char`.

If `<stdint.h>` is available, then you could also use `uint8_t`.

Comment: `uint8_t` is either one byte or a compile error.  `unsigned char` may be larger than one byte (but only on systems where `uint8_t` is a compile error).

Comment: @Ben: `unsigned char` is always a "byte", but in C/C++ parlance, that "byte" may be more than 8 bits (though usually only on architectures that are considered unusual by today's standards).

Answer (score 13):

Don't let the standard compiler type `char` confuse you; the following is perfectly legal:

```
char number[5] = { 1, 4, 3, 6, 2};   // Representation of decimal 14,362
```

It's not that there is anything special about the `char` type that forces you to think of them as characters; rather, it's is their convenient size of just 1 byte that makes them suitable to hold values that library routines such as `printf` use them to hold the 1-byte values that it will interpret as characters under a suitable encoding.

Comment: Yeah, this was new to me. I though that I needed single-quotes around every char. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

`uint_least8_t` is the most compact data type for storing a single decimal digit.

If your system supports a data type of size 1 byte, this will be it.  Otherwise it will be the next smallest data type available.

You may need to cast the value when using a stream insertion operator to make sure you get numeric output instead of character treatment.

Answer (score 1):

The output you're seeing from using cout << on an unsigned char is down to the mechanics of the << operator when used with a std::ostream (specifically, different overloads of the operator << will display the value in different ways - the char/unsigned char overloads usually assume that you want a character representation instead of a numeric one)

The underlying representation of your unsigned char is still the same number which you pushed into the vector - an unsigned char is still an unsigned 1-byte integer)

If you wish to change the output, then you need to avoid using the overload of the << operator which is designed for char or unsigned char - the easiest way to do that is to perform a cast

```
vector<unsigned char> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);

for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    cout << static_cast<int>( v[i] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using char or unsigned char as 1 byte integer type is not always that straightforward... Sometimes you just need the type to be number type, not character type. One such example is here: [1 byte integer data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804591/1-byte-integer-data-type)
Other is when you have function overloaded for arguments of several different types.