# 1 byte integer data type

Tags: c++, char, hex, int, uint8t

I wrote the following code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <stdint.h>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     uint8_t c;

     cin  >> hex >> c;
     cout << dec << c;

     return 0;
 }
```

But when I input `c`—hex for 12—the output is also `c`. I was expecting 12. Later I learned that:

> `uint8_t` is usually a typedef for `unsigned char`. So it's actually reading `c` as ASCII 0x63.

Is there a 1 byte integer which behaves as an integer while doing I/O and not as char?

Comment: No there isn't, which is a shame

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of.

You could do the I/O using a wider integer type, and use range checking and casting as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't know of a way either, but reading a hex number into an integer type can be accomplished as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    short c;
    cin >> std::hex >> c;
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```